# How to calcuate the sum of 1/x, where x is an integer not containing the digit 9 and 10,000,000 ≤ x ≤ 88,888,888

Tags: memory, summation

My code is:

```
nonine[x_] := If[StringMatchQ[IntegerString[x], "*9*"], False, True];
SetAttribute[nonine, Listable];

tbl = Select[Range[10^2, 888], nonine[#] &];

Total[1.0/tbl]
```

got out of memory problem.

Comment: Welcome to mma.se by the way! This looks like a project Euler question, is that right?

Comment: I found it on zhihu, which is  a copycat of Quora in China.

Comment: @ErikE there are more numbers containing 9 than numbers that are free of 9. There only has to be one 9 in the entire number.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom There is a way to do in microseconds the mere summing of all the numbers: `36 * 11111111 * 9 ^ 7 - 36 * 1111111 * 9 ^ 4`. However, I missed that the request was for the sum of `1/x` for each number, which is not so simple. My apologies for the mistake.

Comment: @ErikE, no problem, I appreciate the discussion :). If you follow up your comment with more thinking of your own, you are open minded and you are careful to delete any comments that turn out to have little relevance to the Q&A, like you did/have, then by all means post away (I'd say) :). Not saying you should always remove silly comments, but in a nice Q&A like this it is nice to keep things tidy IMO :). (*temporary message*)

Answer (score 11):

**Update**

This runs in about half a second:

```
Total[1.0 ~Divide~ Flatten@Outer[Plus,
     Range[0, 8],
     Range[0, 80, 10],
     Range[0, 800, 100],
     Range[0, 8000, 1000],
     Range[0, 80000, 10000],
     Range[0, 800000, 100000],
     Range[0, 8000000, 1000000],
     Range[10000000, 80000000, 10000000]]]

(* 1.07145 *)
```

**Original**

This is far from elegant, but runs in a couple of seconds:

```
Compile[{},
  Block[{s = 0.},
   Do[s += 1./(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h),
    {a, 0, 8},
    {b, 0, 80, 10},
    {c, 0, 800, 100},
    {d, 0, 8000, 1000},
    {e, 0, 80000, 10000},
    {f, 0, 800000, 100000},
    {g, 0, 8000000, 1000000},
    {h, 10000000, 80000000, 10000000}];
   s]][]

(* 1.07145 *)
```

Comment: You beat me to adding `Outer`. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I tried `Outer` originally but kept getting an out of memory crash. The problem was using `/` for the division, as soon as I put `Divide` in instead it worked.

Comment: This is amazing (+1)- can you explain why `Flatten@Outer[10^8 #1 + 10^7 #2 + 10^6 #3 + 10^5 #4 + 10^4 #5 + 10^3 #6 +10^2 #2 + 10 #1 &, Range[1, 8], Range[0, 8], Range[0, 8], Range[0, 8], Range[0, 8], Range[0, 8], Range[0, 8], Range[0, 8]]` takes that much longer?

Comment: @gpap, all those extra multiplications make a difference! That pure function is called nearly 79 million times...

Comment: @SimonWoods ah, I am being daft. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonWoods: Neat, as usual. +1

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution is neat, fast, and memory-saving!

Comment: @user2218402 do note that this is a relatively memory intensive approach.

Answer (score 5):

With the definitions

```
a = 10000000;
b = 88888888;

createLookUp[nn_] := 
 Boole[! MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#], 9]] & /@ Range[nn]

unless9Rec = Function[If[! MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#], 9], 1/#, 0]]

cfu =
  Compile[
   {{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}, {lookup, _Integer, 1}}
   ,
   Block[
    {sum, len, largeFixedInt, min, max, nn},
    largeFixedInt = 0;
    sum = 0.;
    nn = Length@lookup;
    min = Quotient[a, nn, 1] + 1;
    max = Quotient[b, nn];
    Do[
     largeFixedInt = nn*ii;
     If[
      lookup[[ii]] == 1
      ,
      Do[
        If[
         lookup[[jj]] == 1,
         sum += 1/(largeFixedInt + jj)
         ]
        ,
        {jj, nn}
        ];

      ]
     ,
     {ii, min, max}

     ];
    sum

    ]

   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

We have

```
(
  nn = 1*^4;
  lookup = createLookUp[nn]; ;
  unless9Rec[a] + cfu[a, b, lookup] - unless9Rec[Ceiling[b, nn]])
  ) // Timing
```

{0.358173, 1.07145}

Comment: It would be a performance hit to always access the lookup table by first subtracting 1. This code should translate to C relatively easily, where arrays start at 0.

Answer (score 4):

All the functions you need are compilable, so you might just `Compile` your code to gain some speed :

```
sum = Compile[{{start, _Integer}, {end, _Integer}, {digit, _Integer}},
        Module[{out = 0., counter = start},
          While[counter <= end, 
                out = out + (1./counter)  Boole[Not[MemberQ[IntegerDigits[counter], digit]]];   
                counter++] ;
           out
         ]
        ]

sum[10000000, 88888888, 9] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {18.919000, 1.07145} *)
```

Compiling to "C" (just add `, CompilationTarget -> "C"` to the above) :

```
sumC[10000000, 88888888, 9] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {11.663000, 1.07145} *)
```

As it is, the code by @RunnyKine is not compilable, so the comparison is not favorable :

```
(x = 0.; 
 For[i = 10000000, 
     i <= 88888888, 
     i++, 
     If[StringMatchQ[IntegerString[i], "*9*"] == False,  x += 1./i]
 ]; 
 x) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {275.261000, 1.07145} *)
```

Comment: Nice answer, it seems we get the same results. You are hardcore for waiting the 275 seconds :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks, but I just left it running and did something else. It probably took you longer to write your (better) code.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, it took me a while to get it right. I always take long, that's my secret :P. I have to make up for it with fast code ;). By the way it was nice to see we had exactly the same code for testing if the `IntegerDigits` contained a 9.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating much more work than needed, try something like:

```
Sum[1/FromDigits[IntegerDigits[x, 9]], {x, 4782969, 43046720}]
```

This should complete on any machine with decent memory size (I'm on netbook at moment, can't verify that). Use `N` inside sum if arbitrary precision is not needed.

The structure of the digits in your query should be a clue...

Edit: This completed (took a while) on my netbook using machine precision, so should certainly be fine on a "real" machine at arbitrary precision. Using the clue, probably even a more direct way to get this. Of course, compile away if a precise answer is not needed.

Another way of doing this directly without the wasted work of a naive solution is:

```
Total@(1/FromDigits /@ Tuples[Join[{Range[8]}, ConstantArray[Range[0, 8], 7]]])
```

This again only operates on the numbers that matter, generated rather than filtered and wasting time. A similar construct can trivially be adapted to any conditions, e.g. "No nines anywhere and no 6 in the sixth digit", etc.

Neat question, and a good example of speed via thinking about the characteristics of the problem (naive brute-force is doing over double the work needed to solve this) vs speeding up unneeded work.

Answer (score 2):

A functional version is not *that* terrible in 29 seconds:

```
AbsoluteTiming@
 Fold[#1 + If[MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#2], 9], 0., 1./#2] &, 0., 
  Range[10000000, 88888888]]
```

> {28.718411, 1.07145}

but if you go to arbitrary precision arithmetic it becomes prohibitive I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking *Mathematica* to compute approximately 80,000,000 rational numbers with large numerators and denominators. It not too surprising that you ran out of memory. If machine precision reals are good enough, then you might try

```
Plus @@ (1/N @ Select[Range[10000000, 88888888], Not @ MemberQ[IntegerDigits[#], 9] &])
```

> 1.07145

% // FullForm

> 1.0714523172876622

Comment: This is incorrect. Opposite of what OP is asking for...

Comment: @rasher. Thanks for pointing out my error. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `For` loop that doesn't cost you any memory:

```
(x = 0.; For[i = 10000000, i <= 88888888, i++, 
  If[StringMatchQ[IntegerString[i], "*9*"] == False, x += 1./i]]; x)
```

You should get:

> 1.07145232

**Edit**

I initially wrote my answer to solve the memory problem, but I guess if speed is also an issue as it usually is with *Mathematica* one can compile my code easily by changing the predicate. So here is a compiled version:

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {y, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{sum = 0., i}, 
   For[i = x, i <= y, i++, If[MemberQ[IntegerDigits[i], 9] == False, sum += Divide[1., i]]]; sum],
 CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

So

```
f[10000000, 88888888] // AbsoluteTiming
```

{10.618008, 1.07145232}

Answer (score 0):

You can compute it in chunks, and then sum the values of the chunks.
For example, something like

```
Total[1.0/Select[Range[k, k + chunk - 1], nonine[#] &]]
```